# How to use TCPDF to generate a PDF417 2D barcode?

Tags: php, barcode, tcpdf

I recently found the TCPDF library to generate PDF with PHP.

A method to generate 2D barcode is also included.

I want to use this feature to generate PDF417 ad Aztec barcode without generating a PDF file. (Like saving it to a file (PMG. SVG, etc) I looked at the included files to see if I can find the code I need, but I didn't find anything.

On the website, akk the exemples are based on the fact that people want a PDF file... I jsut want the image :)

Any suggestion? I don't want to pay 400$ for a barcode :(

Answer (score 4):

@Bimal answered the question but here is an example.

Download the "min" package from the TCPDF sourceforge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/files/tcpdf_min_6_0_025.zip/download)

Unpack the zip file into your WWW folder

Create a new PHP file e.g. `barcode.php`

include the `tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php` in your PHP

create a new `TCPDF2DBarcode object`

generate the PNG barcode using `getBarcodePNG()`

e.g.:

```
<?php

require_once ("tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php");

$code = "hello";
$type = "PDF417";

$barcodeobj = new TCPDF2DBarcode($code, $type);

$barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG();

?>
```

The last line actually generates the image/png data, so you could call this from another PHP script which wraps the output of this in a webpage. e.g.

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="barcode.php" />
</body>
</html>
```

The include file does use some other include files so might be worth pruning all the unnecessary PDF generating stuff once you have it working.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [TCPDF2DBarCode Class](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF2DBarcode.html). You would be using [setBarcode()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF2DBarcode.html#ae50f0ccd1e2c23cac0cefa2a8f02f231) method to set a barcode. Next to fetch it in your specific format you can use methods like:

1. getBarcodePNG()
2. getBarcodeHTML()
3. getBarcodeSVG()

Do check out the documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Other option for use is

```
<?php

require_once ("tcpdf_barcodes_2d.php");

$code = "Esta es una prueba de codigo FFYL";
$type = "PDF417";

$barcodeobj = new TCPDF2DBarcode($code, $type);

//$barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG();

echo $barcodeobj->getBarcodeHTML(2,2);

?>
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($barcodeobj->getBarcodePngData(2,2)); ?>">
```

In this form the image is integrate with the page html and is perfect for send html in email

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, after trying I found that [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) do not support Aztec right now, but PDF417 is OK.